# Ruby ajax on page loading with date data

Tags: ruby, ajax

```
$(function() {  
  function filter_by_year(){ 
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var currentyear = currentdate.getFullYear(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/home/event_list_view',
        data: {},
        beforeSend:function(){          
          $('#filter_div').html('<h6 class="normal-font color-black bold margin-bottom-20">Please wait..</h6>');             
        },
        success:function(data){          
          $('#filter_div').html(data);   
        },
```

i want to pass the currentyear along with ajax data. i tried like,

```
data: {currentyear: currentyear},
```

but it won't pass the value.why?

Comment: paste your console output of request

Comment: I tried this and its working fine. Can you please check again?

Comment: Why data parameter is empty in code snippet? Is it missed by you or you are aware about it?

Comment: Why would you want to send the current year from the client to your server? Your server already knows what year it is, and the client could be wrong